# Forever vs. Node-Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, forever

Does Forever create a Windows Service?

I have Forever running Node on a Windows Server, but when I log out of my account on the server, the Forever process terminates. I was under the impression that a Forever daemon is the same as a Windows Service, which would continue to run after user log out. It seems [Node-Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) will create a Windows Service to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forever should work fine, but the user running it has to be active. Just run it as a service account rather than as a logon user in Windows and you should be fine.

Comment: We were able to run forever through our service account, but it seems the process is not creating a Windows Service (doesn't show up in the list of Services) - it's still terminating whenever we log off.

Comment: It won't create it by itself, you've got the order of operations reversed.  You create a windows service that runs the process, not the other way around.

Comment: OH, I see. I ended up using Node-Windows which created the windows service for me and has been working great. I'll keep that in mind for the future though. Thanks for your help!